# Question marks instead of citation

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, back-referencing, cite-package

I'm a new user for LaTeX, I'm using `svmult` for springer, but there sth I can't get it about `thebibliography`.
I use the following packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{svmult}
%
\usepackage{makeidx}         
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{amsmath}         
\usepackage{eqnarray}  
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{cite}    
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}    % places footnotes at page 
%
%
% the input bibligraphy file
\begin{thebibliography}{23}
\bibitem[%no.]{%type}
\end{thebibliography}
```

I get a question marks `??` instead of citation numbers besides.

Another thing I don't know how to access to sec or figure by cross-references, in the reference guide the recommended `oribibl` but it doesn't work with me.

I got the whole package of CTAN by MiKTeX 2.9

> if there is any forgotten one in the above code

## Example ##

```
\documentclass[10pt]{svmult}

\usepackage{makeidx}         
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{amsmath}         
\usepackage{eqnarray}  
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{cite}    
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeindex 

%%

\begin{document}
\title*{My examle}
\author{Hend \inst{1}}
\institute{University
  \texttt{sth@gmail.com}}
%%
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
first paragraph
\\
\keywords{keywords}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:1}
Ref one goes here
\cite{[1]}.  
\paragraph{}
multi-ref
\cite{2--4}.
\input{exreference}
%%%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

And the input reference as

```
\begin{thebibliography}{23}

%references
\bibitem[1]{journal} Krippner, P., Beer, D.: AOI testing positions in comparisons. Circuit Assembly, \textbf{15}, 26--32 (2004)

\bibitem[2]{journal} Jiang, B.C., Wang, C.C., Hsu, Y.N.: Machine vision and background remover-based approach for PCB solder joints inspection. International Journal of Production Research, \textbf{45}, 451--464 (2007)

\bibitem[3]{journal} Acciani, G., Brunetti, G., Fornarelli, G.: A multiple neural network system to classify solder joints on integrated circuits. International Journal of Computational Intelligence Research, \textbf{2}, 337--348 (2006) 

\bibitem[4]{journal} Mar, N.S.S., Fookes, C., Yarlagadda, P.K.D.V.: Design and development of automatic visual inspection system for PCB manufacturing. Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing, \textbf{27}, 949--962 (2011)
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you run `latex`, then `bibtex`, then `latex` again (possibly twice)?

Comment: I tried it, still the same

Comment: As it stands, this is going to be hard to help with: we need a full example document to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue. It was because the symbol "|" was not recognized correctly, leading to the text around in rendering improperly. This also made the citations; cross-references show up as "?". So if somebody is still getting this issue check the text. Probably that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to `\bibitem` are

1. An optional “identification”
2. A mandatory key for reference

So with

```
\bibitem[KB]{Krippner-Beer2004} ...
```

you'd get

> [KB]

when inputting `\cite{Krippner-Beer2004}`. The key is an arbitrary string that identifies univocally the item.

You probably don't want symbolic references, but numeric ones, so you shouldn't use the optional argument.

Modify your bibliography subfile like

```
\begin{thebibliography}{4}

%references
\bibitem{KB2004} Krippner, P., Beer, D.: AOI testing positions in comparisons. Circuit Assembly, \textbf{15}, 26--32 (2004)

\bibitem{JWH2007} Jiang, B.C., Wang, C.C., Hsu, Y.N.: Machine vision and background remover-based approach for PCB solder joints inspection. International Journal of Production Research, \textbf{45}, 451--464 (2007)

\bibitem{ABF2006} Acciani, G., Brunetti, G., Fornarelli, G.: A multiple neural network system to classify solder joints on integrated circuits. International Journal of Computational Intelligence Research, \textbf{2}, 337--348 (2006) 

\bibitem{MFY2011} Mar, N.S.S., Fookes, C., Yarlagadda, P.K.D.V.: Design and development of automatic visual inspection system for PCB manufacturing. Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing, \textbf{27}, 949--962 (2011)

\end{thebibliography}
```

and use `\cite{MFY2011}` when you want to cite the last paper. For a range, use

```
\cite{JWH2007}--\cite{MFY2011}
```

---

Unrelated, but important: it's

```
\abstract{Sirst paragraph

Second paragraph

\keywords{keywords}
}
```

and not

```
\begin{abstract}
first paragraph
\\
\keywords{keywords}
\end{abstract}
```

because `\abstract` is a command with argument and not an environment in `svmult`

Comment: thanks , but for the keywords and abstract they discussed by commands in the springer reference guide as I wrote.
Really thanks a lot for being so helpful and for the notes.